# Regular Expression to find annotations in single/multiline for Java class

Tags: java, regex, annotations

I want to develop a Regular Expression in Java to find annotations in single/multiline for Java class. Just now I am trying this one

```
String regExp = "^\\s*(@.+)$";
```

but it works on single line only, not working on multiline .e.g.

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "nativeSQL", query = "SELECT emp1.emp_id, emp1.name, emp1.manager_id, "
+ "emp1.dept_id, emp1.address_id " + "FROM EMP emp1, EMP emp2 "
+ "WHERE ((emp2.EMP_ID = ?) AND (emp2.EMP_ID = emp1.MANAGER_ID))", resultClass = Professor.class)
```

In the given example I want to extract the key-value pair e.g.

```
name = "nativeSQL"
query = "SELECT emp1.emp_id, emp1.name, emp1.manager_id, "
+ "emp1.dept_id, emp1.addr
```

Comment: Have you considered using something like parboiled instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code you can use to extract `name` and `query` in a multiline annotation expression:

```
String line = "@NamedNativeQuery(name = \"nativeSQL\", query = \"SELECT emp1.emp_id, emp1.name, emp1.manager_id, \"\n" + 
"+ \"emp1.dept_id, emp1.address_id \" + \"FROM EMP emp1, EMP emp2 \"\n" +
"+ \"WHERE ((emp2.EMP_ID = ?) AND (emp2.EMP_ID = emp1.MANAGER_ID))\", resultClass = Professor.class)\n";
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("^\\s*@NamedNativeQuery\\(\\s*name\\s*=\\s*\"(.+)\"\\s*,\\s*query\\s*=\\s*\"(.+)\"\\s*,", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = pt.matcher(line);
if (m.find())
   System.out.println("name: [" + m.group(1) + "] query: [" + m.group(2) + ']');
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
name: [nativeSQL] query: [SELECT emp1.emp_id, emp1.name, emp1.manager_id, "
+ "emp1.dept_id, emp1.address_id " + "FROM EMP emp1, EMP emp2 "
+ "WHERE ((emp2.EMP_ID = ?) AND (emp2.EMP_ID = emp1.MANAGER_ID))]
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes your regular expression will definitely work but it works only for given Java source lines, not the other one. Actually the given lines just for examples to understand my problems. But need a regex to grap all types of annotations in Java e.g. @Column(name = "EMP_ID")           @Table(name = "EMP")

Comment: You may need to tweak this regex to suite the changing needs of your annotation lines. Since I don't know all of your cases, I can't cover all of them in my answer.